# Magento 2 - Transfer cart items from API to web store

Tags: magento, magento2, checkout

I am creating a complex shopping configurator app that allows a user to customize and visualize a product which consists of multiple store items. Once they confirm their purchase, I iterate and add all of the selected products to a guest cart using the `.../rest/V1/guest-carts` API endpoint.

I would now like to forward the user to the store checkout to continue the purchasing process from the web store, e.g. `https://store.url/checkout/cart`. Of course, that basket needs to be populated with the items that were added via the API. I've looked through the documentation but not been able to find 
anything relevant but I wonder if I can pass over the `store_id` or the `quote_id` and the relevant products be inserted accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is still relevant for you but, I was also working on a similar problem and came across this [plugin](https://github.com/Vendic/magento2-external-checkout) for Magento 2. Basically what this plugin does is use a customer's `token` and a `quote_id` and creates a temporary session on the Magento2 Store and then redirect the user to the checkout page. This was a starting point for me, as I had to customize this plugin further to suit my requirements.

Hope this helps.